# How to read HTML from a webpage and interact with it as your own in a WPF application

Tags: html, wpf, vb.net, web, web-crawler

Hey, I don't exactly know where to go with this question. I've search numerous hours, but I haven't been able to find the appropriate solution. What I want to do: Get the html of a certain webpage (Lets say in this case http://www.google.com). I want to show this html within my wpf application, so that you can see the content of the page you requested. Then I want to be able to trigger events on the html that has been loaded from the URL. Like I want you to be able to click on a certain node in the HTML and I want to be able to link this node to a certain value. Basically a crawler application that let's you request a page, see the page in a control and allows you to click in the loaded HTML and link values to predefined values you set. So basically I want to be able to get a webpage displayed within my application and be able to trigger events on the html (For example a click on the html which would need me to know on what node you clicked in the html, or for example be able to edit the html by clicking in it). Anyone got any idea? Any help would be highly appreciated! An example of software like this: http://www.visualwebripper.com/

Any help to point me in the good direction would be higly appreciated! I have searched and searched, but haven't been able to come to a solution as I'm new to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should look at WebBrowser control? It allows to inspect HTML content and to call JavaScript methods in an HTML web page or let them call your WPF code.